# Trying to send the existing excel file to UI, as a response from node backend

Tags: node.js, excel, express

Requirment: Send an existing excel file in the mount path to UI, as a response from node backend
Issue: File is being downloaded but in an encoded/corrupt format

What have I tried?

```
var fileName = filePath + req.body.report_name + ".xlsx";

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
res.download(fileName);
```

When I download the same file by calling API directly from browser, it just works fine. But when I try downloading it from the React UI app, it just downloads in corrupted format.

Comment: Check again your original file what stored in server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, JFYIP when I download the same file by calling API directly from browser, it just works fine. But when I try downloading it from the React UI app, it just downloads in corrupted format.

Comment: Update: This was not an issue at server end. It was an issue at frontend. Resolved the above issue by adding a key to request parameters and it worked like a charm.
Just added the below key in request parameters before making a post/get call
responseType:'arraybuffer'